# button will not onclick correctly and I cannot figure out why

Tags: html, css, button, onclick

So the idea is just to have this  switch pages to "explore.html" when it clicked but I've been trying to get it to work for hours and it won't. I've tried changing it to a "href=()" and it didn't work either. Do I just write it as an  instead of a ?[click here to see the code I'm having trouble with...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpsSK.jpg)

Comment: Wow, I really cannot read that. Supply it as part of the question as _text_ instead please?

Comment: Please check the below code. If any changes please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your onclick as follow

From :

```
onclick="explore.html"
```

to

```
onclick="window.location = 'explore.html'"
```

Comment: Thank you guys!! These were helpful. With this implication it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong, As on click function you are giving a link directly which is not the correct syntax for on click, you need to apply the window location for it where you want to redirect, here is the code for the button  to redirect, and if you want to use href then you need to use anchor tag and need to apply a css to same to make it like button

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='/linktoredirect'">Continue</button>
```

href using anchor tag

```
<a href="/linktoredirect">Continue</a>
```

Or you can use like following

```
<form method="get" action="/linktoredirect">
    <button type="submit">click</button>
</form>
```

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

onclick is an event. If you want to redirect other page then use "href".
example:

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```